# How to write the correct SQL query to find the most duplicate user?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

That's my database design.
[image]

I need to find the person with the most albums using SQLite.
I tried this:

```
SELECT USERS.NAME, COUNT(USERS.NAME) AS 'value_occurrence' FROM USERS
INNER JOIN ALBUMS
ON USERS.ID = ALBUMS.USER_ID 
GROUP BY USERS.NAME 
ORDER BY 'value_occurrence' 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

but it didn't work and gave me the wrong result. Please help me find the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is correct, but you may be getting tripped up by incorrect use of single quotes for aliases.  Try this version:

```sql
SELECT u.NAME, COUNT(u.NAME) AS value_occurrence
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN ALBUMS a ON a.USER_ID = u.ID
GROUP BY u.NAME
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The problem with `ORDER BY 'value_occurrence'` is that you are telling SQLite to order by a constant value.  That is, *every* record in the result set will have the same value for ordering, which basically means that SQLite is free to choose *any* record as being the "first."

Note: As the answer by @Cazzym mentioned, you should be aggregating by the user `ID`, in case two or more users might have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The code basically looks fine, but it will return unexpected results where two users have the same name. That's why we have ID columns!

Try

```
SELECT USERS.NAME, COUNT(USERS.ID) AS 'value_occurrence' FROM USERS
INNER JOIN ALBUMS
ON USERS.ID = ALBUMS.USER_ID 
GROUP BY USERS.ID, USERS.NAME
ORDER BY 'value_occurrence' 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

We can use `group by Users.Id, Users.Name` because each ID is going to only have one name associated with it, so it's still going to only create a single group per ID.